# Is it better to save this.state.someData in variables, instead of refferring to state directly in render?

Tags: reactjs, render, state

Like this:

```
render() {
   let data = this.state.data;

   return(
       <div prop={data} />
   );
}
```

Is there any differnece at all? Instead of just replacing `data` with `this.state.data`?

Comment: You can use that, there is nothing to worry about it, as you have placed, let data = this.state.data; inside the render function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice approach to shorten the variables you need from `state` or `props` or any other nested objects in general.
I find that more readable and easy to understand what data this function needs.
I follow this pattern (well a bit different pattern actually, coming up) in all of my functions, not just the `render`.

You can use the [ES6 Destructuring feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to make it even more concise:

```
 render() {
   const {data, otherData} = this.state;

   return(
       <div prop={data} otherProp={otherData} />
   );
}
```

Performance wise, there is no differnece.